# Why is there a voting limit restriction on Meta?

Tags: discussion, meta, voting-limits

Nearly every day recently, I'll use up *all* my post *and* comment votes here on [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/). Why do we have the voting limit here?

Comment: To keep users from going "turbo".

Comment: All other stuff like posts, comments and even edits are easy to track down and undo if needed however votes are highly anonymous and even a dev need lots of effort to track it down if needed. So imagine someone angry with the system and everyone who will downvote 1000 posts in one day.

Comment: Won't the vote anomaly detector catch 1000 downvotes in one day anyhow?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Is there maybe a window nearby you right now? Look through that window.

[image]

There's some cool stuff out there.

---

Image copyright Stephanie Saries, offered under a [CC BY-NC-ND 2.0 license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-nc-nd/2.0/); [her Flickr page for the photo](http://www.flickr.com/photos/einahpets32/4931207926/).

Comment: I just looked through my window and you sir are a liar!

Comment: @PeeHaa: Try a different window. This may require going to another building.

Comment: It's like getting upvotes on SO for a bikeshed answer, @Cole; I just don't feel any need to gain reputation from this, even though I'm serious about it. It didn't take me enough effort.

Comment: Is that what they refer to as "outside"?

Comment: @Bart Is that a foreign language?

Comment: The funny part about this is that I've actually been sitting outside all day in my beautiful backyard. Thanks to the magic of extension cords and Wi-Fi, though, I can still code and waste time on SO.

Answer (score 14):

The point is to prevent users from vote-spamming the site to an extent.

That need to prevent spam exists on meta sites, as well as main sites.