# Increase vote limits on meta sites

Tags: feature-request, voting-limits

Since [voting is different on meta](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta), and meta sites actively promote discussion and expressing your opinions - it is also more frequent to cast a vote as a user. I've seen [why is there a voting limit restriction on meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/190701/why-is-there-a-voting-limit-restriction-on-meta) and feel more or less the same.

Twice in as many days I've used up my voting quota on [meta stackoverflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) quite early on in the day, and I suspect this to be a common phenomenon - but is it *necessary* to apply the same voting rules as per the rest of the network?

Would it be beneficial to increase (up/down) vote limits on meta sites?

Comment: You shouldn't want to spend more time on a meta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Would it be beneficial to increase (up/down) vote limits on meta sites?

### No

While voting on meta sites is encouraged, if you find yourself with no votes left for the day - take it as encouragement to do something else, rather than curtailment of your enthusiasm.

*For me, this was a "new-user" activity blip, caused by first access after the meta split which didn't last beyond a few days. Having not participated on MSE/MSO before all questions were new, and (refreshingly) most of them interesting, leading to it being quite easy to burn through all votes in little time supporting or disagreeing with questions/answers/comments. However, meta sites are much less active than their sibling sites; and therefore in normal use it's not that likely to persistently use all of your votes unless you're using them without discretion.*