# Should the post-ban threshold be adjusted on MSE?

Tags: bug, status-completed, meta, post-ban

*as of writing I have [one previous question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/231879/increase-vote-limits-on-meta-sites) here on meta, which was a feature-request, it hasn't been well received and thus has downvotes (overall -6).*

---

According to the help page:

> Voting is different on meta.
>
> On posts tagged feature-request, voting indicates agreement or disagreement

Considering asking a question just now I see:

[image: warning after one question]

Should the note in [what's meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) about meta stackexchange be further expanded? Right now it reads:

> On other Stack Exchange sites, if you have an account on the main
>   site, you have an account on its meta site. On Meta Stack Exchange,
>   everyone must create a separate account.
>
> Votes on Meta Stack Exchange
>   directly affect your reputation on Meta Stack Exchange only; they do
>   not affect your reputation on any other Stack Exchange site. Badges on
>   Meta Stack Exchange are also separate from badges on any other site.

It gives no warning that you may find yourself in my current scenario (it's perfectly understandable, given that MSE is separate).

Or should the post-ban thresholds be adjusted on *this* meta site?

Comment: Related: [Get rid of the question ban on Meta; suspend actively harmful users manually](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/179093/get-rid-of-the-question-ban-on-meta-suspend-actively-harmful-users-manually) - this could be a duplicate, but your warning message suggests this was changed in the MSO/MSE split (may be intentionally, or maybe unintentionally)

Comment: Assuming things on M.SE are how they were on the pre-split M.SO, there's a significantly higher threshold for hitting the ban here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67023/should-the-automated-ban-on-questions-used-on-so-apply-to-meta-as-well

Comment: We derped when rolling out something new (by forgetting the limit is considerably higher here) - sorry about that!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The threshold here *is* significantly higher. The current implementation is only likely to stop:

- Those that repeatedly post duplicate, ill-researched, unfounded or extremely bizarre yet *serious* attempts at discussions, feature requests or support cases
- Those here purely for creative lulz, well, most of the time

If you *are* blocked and you firmly believe that you don't fall into either category, or have fallen into the first and are *serious* about adjusting the way that you interact with this community, you can [contact us](https://meta.stackexchange.com/contact) and we can have a look. If you've got a *whopper* of a lead balloon or two holding you back from participating positively, we're *generally* going to be inclined to help you.

If this becomes a pattern for you, or if we couldn't hope to get you out of a block even with a crane, then *this isn't the best place for you to participate* - not everyone is well-suited to argue on capital hill, and you shouldn't feel bad about that.

We do not have automatic question blocks enabled on any other meta site.

You should not have seen the warning that you did - you're not in any danger of being blocked. What happened was, the setting for where the prompt kicks in was still at the level that it would be on Stack Overflow, even though the threshold here is *much* higher. I've adjusted it so that folks will see it *only* if they're approaching the higher threshold, which is quite difficult to do, but it'll kick in *slightly* sooner (by way of comparison) since voting here is quite, well, unrestrained :)

Comment: Since I know someone is likely to ask, the block threshold here is approximately _six times_ higher than it is on Stack Overflow. It's excruciatingly hard to hit for someone that is here for the right reasons and actually learns from previous mistakes.